# Can (pdf)LaTeX recognize text strings and replace (expand) them?

Tags: macros, pdftex, expansion

I'd like LaTeX to replace `e^` with `\mathrm{e}^`. I know I could just make a macro `\e` that does this, but I know I'll forget using it..

Can LaTeX find and replace and replace letter combinations (I don't mean a *find and replace* function of the editor, I mean a true TeX, macro-like expansion).

Comment: You could, in theory, make `e` an active character (like `~`) and let it test if the next character is `^` and then expand to `\mathrm{e}`, but this would be kind of overkill and would break other usages of `e`, like it is no longer allowed in macro names! You could limit this just to mathmode, which would improve that situation. I personally would go for the mentioned `\e` or search&replace using your editor.

Comment: You could make `e` an active character, but I think that would be a disaster. Is this just in math mode? If so, make `e` active only in math mode _may_ work, but again could be problematic.

Comment: A search and replace of `e^` with `\mathrm{e}^` makes more sense.

Comment: If you are willing to use XeTeX, the `xesearch` package can do this.  (But Herbert is probably right.)

Comment: hmm, yes... All the smart people say it's impossible.. Could someone make this into an answer ? This way I can commit and close the question.

Comment: Much less problematic by using \mathcode\`\e="8000. I'll try to make some working code soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can activate `e` only in math mode and only as a math character with mathcode `"8000`, that doesn't interfere with macro name scanning:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`e\lowercase{\endgroup
  \edef~{\noexpand\mathrm{\mathchar\the\mathcode`e}}}
\mathcode`e="8000

\begin{document}
$e^x\leq e^y$
\end{document}
```

but I advise against using such an approach. It's better to have a macro `\euler` or any other name.

In order to use the special `"8000` mathcode assigned to `e`, there must exist a valid definition of `e` as active character. Therefore the well-known `\lowercase` trick (many commands used there have `e` in their names).

Answer (score 3):

In plain TeX, `'` is defined in a rather tricky way, so that multiple consecutive `'` behave properly. For that (and probably other reasons), Knuth introduced the possibility for a character which is normally not active to be active in math mode. This is setup by `` \mathcode`\e="8000 ``. We define an active `e` to check for the next character and decide whether to become `\mathrm{e}` or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\~=13\relax
\lccode`\~=`\e% pretend that a lowercase "~" is "e".
\lccode`\^=`\^% make sure it doesn't get change (who knows...)
\lowercase{\endgroup % restore the former catcodes and lccodes.
  \newcommand{~}{\@ifnextchar^{\@firstoftwo{\mathrm{\true@e}^}}{\true@e}}%
  \edef\true@e{\mathchar\the\mathcode`\e}% save the true e.
}
\mathcode`\e="8000\relax


\begin{document}

As everyone knows, $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ and if $e=0$, $\frac{1}{e}$ blows up. Of course, we can try more complicated things:
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^{e^{e_a^b}}+e_a^{e^a}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: so there's actually no problem in defining it this way? The other post made me worry about macro breaking etc. What's your take on that?

Comment: @romeovs: This will pose no problem as long as no one else is trying to define an active character `e`. This will normally not happen (because of the many problems it entails when done outside math mode, as described in other posts), so I think that you are safe. Although... I would advise against doing that for _all_ the letters, or having crazy definitions, simply because it makes the code harder to understand. You may run into trouble if you try to do the same with e.g. `~`. Or `:` in a french document, etc, when those are made active.

Answer (score 2):

(Just summarising the comments.)

You *could* technically do it by making `e` an active character, but that will break all sorts of things and probably is not worth the while.

Defining `\e` or just doing a search and replace is probably a better idea.