# Active characters after \begin{document}

Tags: math-mode, catcodes

I'm using XeLaTeX and I want to do automatic repeating of plus sign after breakline. I've found [the unoffical package](https://github.com/dryabov/rumathbr) for this but it seems to me a bit overkill (although didn't try it).

I tried to modify the example in [Can (pdf)LaTeX recognize text strings and replace (expand) them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/can-pdflatex-recognize-text-strings-and-replace-expand-them/15761#15761), I've just rewritten 'e's to the '+'s. This works as long as the macro is defined after `\begin{document}`, if I put it before it worked only for the letters (not for the plus).

I also tried a little different approach, I found [here](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/olsak/tbn.html):

```
{\catcode`\+=13 \expandafter }\expandafter \newcommand\noexpand+{\mathplus\discretionary{}{+}{}}
\mathchardef\mathplus=\mathcode`\+  % + character in math mode
\mathcode`\+="8000  % set + active in math mode, otherwise inactive
\binoppenalty=10000 % do not break elsewhere
```

This is the same, it works only if I put it after the `\begin{document}` but I want it as a part of my package.

I'm translating it with XeLaTeX and packages: fontspec, amssymb, amsmath, xltxtra, hyperref, geometry and fancyhdr.

I'm really confused by those `llcode` or `expandafter` idioms, so I'll be glad for every piece of advice how to simply solve my problem.

Answer (score 13):

First of all a little bit of theory: when TeX finds a character of category 11 or 12 in math mode, it looks at its mathcode; for example, the usual mathcode of `+` is `"202B` in hexadecimal form, which means

> `+` an operation symbol (first digit `"2`); the character must be taken from math family `"0` (second digit); use the character in slot `"2B` (third and fourth digits).

However, if the mathcode is the special value `"8000`, TeX looks for a definition of that character as if it were active (catcode 13) and uses that in place of it. Plain TeX and LaTeX exploit this feature for `'` in formulas such as `$f''(x)$`, with a clever definition of active `'`.

Therefore the problem is to provide such a definition *without* activating the character. Let's look at the presented code.

```
\mathchardef\mathplus=\mathcode`\+  % + character in math mode
```

This line just provides a command that is an alias for the usual `+`; note that one doesn't need to know the mathcode: that notation access it implicitly.

```
\mathcode`\+="8000  % set + active in math mode, otherwise inactive
```

This assigns the special mathcode to `+`.

```
\binoppenalty=10000 % do not break elsewhere
```

This tells TeX that *no* binary operation symbol is a good point for breaking a line, unless an explicit good break point is manually added: for example a penalty or a discretionary item.

```
{\catcode`\+=13 \expandafter }\expandafter 
  \newcommand\noexpand+{\mathplus\discretionary{}{+}{}}
```

The purpose of this code is to define the active `+` to expand to `\mathplus\discretionary{}{+}{}`. One cannot say

```
{\catcode`\+=13 \gdef+{\mathplus\discretionary{}{+}{}}}
```

because there would be an active `+` in the replacement text and this would lead to infinite recursion, because `+` would be replaced by its definition *ad infinitum*. Thus the `+` is activated in a group and, before the group is closed, the `\noexpand+` is expanded via the two `\expandafter` commands. The expansion of `\noexpand+` is just an active `+` that, however, cannot be expanded just now, because its ability to expand has been nullified. Then the group is closed, but the first `+` (not preceded by `\noexpand` any more) has already been tokenized and TeX sees

```
\newcommand+{\mathplus\discretionary{}{+}{}}
```

where the first `+` is active and the second one isn't. The purpose of `\discretionary` is twofold: first of all it inserts a plus sign with the correct mathcode that qualifies it as a binary operation and provides a break point; secondly, if a break is taken, after the break a `+` is inserted.

A perfectly equivalent definition is

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathplus\discretionary{}{+}{}}
```

because the `\lowercase` would put back into the main token list

```
\endgroup\def+
```

with `+` of the same category code as ~ (that is, active). The `\endgroup` undoes the `\lccode` assignment. The second `+` has category 12 as usual.

However this definition is not as good as it might seem: try, for example

```
\parbox{1pt}{\itshape$a+b$}
```

The `\parbox` with a very small width is just to force a break after the `+`; the `+` at the start of the second line will be from the italic font! Indeed the arguments of `\discretionary` are processed in *horizontal* mode, as if `\mbox` surrounded them (TeXbook, page 287). A more sensible definition would use

```
\discretionary{}{\the\textfont0+}{}
```

Since no break can be taken in subscripts or superscripts, this is quite safe. For the `-` it's another story.

Personal opinion. Some typographical traditions, notably in Russia, use the repetition of operation and relation symbols at breaks. This is a tradition that's worthy of being forgotten as it has no mathematical justification.

Comment: Nice answer! ("Nice answer!" doesn't have 15 characters so I had to add this).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `\begin{document}` changes catcodes (does it?). In any case, changing catcodes might (*will* in your case) break compatibility with a lot of other packages.

Perhaps you are better off to define some sort of environment inside of which your changes are in effect. This has two effects: first, it avoids the problem of `\begin{document}` and second, you can still use other packages inside of the same document.

You could put your code into the respective `\begin{<environment>}` statement.  The changes would last until `\end{<environment>}`.

Comment: `\begin{document}` does nothing with catcodes by itself; some packages (**babel**, for instance) force LaTeX to change some catcodes at `\begin{document}`. The purpose of mathcode `"8000` is just to have the functionality of active characters without actually activating them.