# Automatic reduplication of equal sign in the beginning of broken formula

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Suppose we have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=i=j=k=l=m=n=o=p=q=r=s=t=u=v=w=x=y=z$
\end{document}
```

which produces the following result
[image: Result]

I want to have an additional equal sign automatically added before symbol `s`.

#### UPDATE

The same question about `\leq` and

```
$a \leq b \leq c \leq d \leq e \leq f \leq g \leq h \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq l \leq m \leq n \leq o \leq p \leq q \leq r \leq s \leq t \leq u \leq v \leq w \leq x \leq y \leq z$
```

Comment: Is this method supposed to work for inline-math situations only? The reason I ask is that most display-math environments (other than those of the `breqn` package) force you to choose explicit line break points -- giving you a chance to supply the extra `=` sign. Separately, should you maybe be concerned that consecutive `=` signs without intervening material might confuse your readers?

Comment: I know that this is traditional of Russian typography; but it's unnecessary and, in my opinion, confusing. Perhaps not so much when the equals sign is repeated, but it surely is when a binary operation symbol is repeated.

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking it's unnecessary, but it's a tradition I would like to follow.

Comment: @egreg: Did not know that applied to binary relations as well. Repeating a `-` sign actually changes the meaning as `9 - 5` is different than `9 - -5` (over two line), so am surprised that that is the standard in Russian typography.

Comment: It is applied mainly to `=` and `+`.

Comment: I've added the definition for `\leq` as requested. For `+` it's just like for `=`.

Comment: Thanks. The transformation from the original definition is really unobvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend such repetition. However, with a modification of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28625/4427) you can get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathchardef\mathequals=\mathcode`=
\begingroup\lccode`~=`=
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathequals\discretionary{}{\the\textfont0=}{}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`=="8000 }

\begin{document}
$a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=i=j=k=l=m=n=o=p=q=r=s=t=u=v=w=x=y=z$
\end{document}
```

The `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary because `amsmath` uses the `=` symbol for some of its initializations. It doesn't hurt when `amsmath` is not loaded.

### Other math symbols

Let's see how we can redefine `\leq` to have the same properties as `=`. I adapted a trick that I believe is due to the late Michael J. Downes (the main developer of `amsmath`):

```
\let\mathleq=\leq
\def\getmeaning#1"#2#3{\noexpand\the\textfont"#3\char"}
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\leq{\mathleq\discretionary{}{\expandafter\getmeaning\meaning\mathleq}{}}}\x
```

The expansion of `\meaning\mathleq` is `\mathchar"3214` and we need to save the `2` (which is needed as argument to `\textfont`) leaving `14` in the input stream. After the `\edef` we get

```
\def\leq{\mathleq\discretionary{}{\the\textfont"2\char"14}{}}
```

that is similar to what I used before for `=`.

Comment: I noticed that current version of solution isn't a friend of `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: Now it is fine.

Comment: I managed to adapt your solution to some other binary operation symbols. But I couldn't do it for `\leq`. Could you provide an extended version of solution suitable for this case also ?

Comment: The first part solution for equality symbol breaks cases when `=` is used as part of something else. For example, `\coloneqq` or `:=` is broken up as `:=` and `=`. (This does not bother me but might be useful for readers to know). Surprisingly, the package `rmathbr` *breaks* (here: *makes dysfunctional*) `\coloneq` and `\coloneqq` altogether (at least in conjunction with all other packages I'm using).

Answer (score 2):

From http://dxdy.ru/post82175.html

In preambule:

```
\def\?#1{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}{\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt #1$}}{}}
```

Then you should add `\?` before operations:

```
\begin{document}
$a \?\leq b \?\leq c \?\leq d \?\leq e \?\leq f \?\leq g \?\leq h \?\leq i \?\leq j \?\leq k \?\leq l \?\leq m \?\leq n \?\leq o \?\leq p \?\leq q \?\leq r \?\leq s \?\leq t \?\leq u \?\leq v \?\leq w \?\leq x \?\leq y \?\leq z$
\end{document}
```