# How to add variable arguments to \newcommand inside \SetBreakableRel from the package rmathbr? (inline math-break with repetition)

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, math-operators, inline

> `rmathbr` is a package enabling another convention of breaking inline equations if they run too long. Specifically, symbols are repeated on the new line (and kept on previous line). So, for instance, `a = b` is broken as on `a =` on the first line and `= b` continuing on the second line. The package was **recently updated** (December 2020).
>
> - Please consider using that newest version when attempting to answer the question; otherwise unexpected bugs may be present.

There is a macro called `\SetBreakableRel` in the `rmathbr` package to create compound symbols one would also like to break *with duplication* when necessary (see [documentation](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/rmathbr/rmathbr.pdf)). For example, to get a breakable [image: example usage], one defines a new command `\goesto` as (in the document preamble)

```
\newcommand{\goesto}{\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}}
\SetBreakableRel{\goesto}
```

This works great as far as I am concerned (line is broken and symbol is duplicated):

`$e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e$` gives

[image: Example of how \goesto works]

The **problems begin** when one tries to define new commands (which break and duplicate) that **also take in variable arguments**. For example, if instead of *n* and ∞ one wants to have variables `#1` and `#2`, i.e

```
\newcommand{\goestoarg}[2]{\xrightarrow{#1\to#2}} %<-- this doesn't work
\SetBreakableRel{\goestoarg} %<-- this doesn't work
```

then this gives errors and does not work: for example, `$\goestoarg{a}{b}$` just gives [image: example of faulty output] (this is the wrong symbol to begin with so I didn't attempt to see if it duplicates on line break). To show that the problem is likely from `rmathbr`: if one (only) comments out `\SetBreakableRel{\goestoarg}`, one has the expected output: [image: works without rmathbr]. But, of course, I *want* to have it *uncommented* to enforce line breaking *with duplication* for this relation `\goestoarg`.

- ***Question:*** How does one define `\goestoarg` with two arguments so that it works properly with `\SetBreakableRel`?

I have also tried to put two `#`'s (that is, `##` instead of `#`, see MWE below) to no avail.

---

Here is the code (with some additional packagages to hint at needed compatibility with other packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{rmathbr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\newcommand{\goesto}{\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}} %works great
\SetBreakableRel{\goesto} %works great

%%%%% uncomment as necessary

%\newcommand{\goestoarg}[2]{\xrightarrow{#1\to#2}} %<-- this doesn't work
%\SetBreakableRel{\goestoarg} %<-- this doesn't work

%\newcommand{\Goestoarg}[2]{\xrightarrow{##1\to##2}} %<-- this also doesn't work
%\SetBreakableRel{\Goestoarg} %<-- this also doesn't work


\begin{document}


$e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e$

%$\goestoarg{a}{b}$ %<- does not work
%$\Goestoarg{a}{b}$ %<- also does not work


\end{document}
```

---

Here is the log file from when `\goestoarg` stuff (three lines: the definition, `SetBreakableRel` and usage `$\goestoarg{a}{b}$`) is *uncommented*. This is a subset of the entire log file; I narrowed it down to start when `rmathbr` is loaded because the 30 000 character limit was exceeded. The errors are just before TeX Memory usage output near the end of the log.

```
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/rmathbr\rmathbr.st
y
Package: rmathbr 2020/12/18 1.1.1 Repeating of math operator at the broken line
 and the new line in inline equations

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifetex.sty
Package: ifetex 2019/10/25 v1.3 ifetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.s
ty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.st
y
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.
tex
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils
.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks30
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks31
)
\XKV@depth=\count271
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-02-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backen
d-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count272
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)))
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.
sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.
sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graph
ics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdfte
x.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen164
\Gin@req@width=\dimen165
)
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/parskip\parskip.st
y
Package: parskip 2021-03-14 v2.0h non-zero parskip adjustments

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoption
s.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.
sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetk
eys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.
sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count273
))
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.
sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count274
\Gm@cntv=\count275
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count276
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen166
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen167
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen168
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen169
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen170
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen171
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen172
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen173
\Gm@dimlist=\toks32

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.
cfg))
No file Test12.aux.
\openout1 = `Test12.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LGR/cmr/m/n on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for LGR+cmr on input line 2
7.

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cbfonts-fd\lgrcmr.
fd
File: lgrcmr.fd 2017/07/29 v1.2 Greek European Computer Regular
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 27.

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-p
df.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count277
\scratchdimen=\dimen174
\scratchbox=\box52
\nofMPsegments=\count278
\nofMParguments=\count279
\everyMPshowfont=\toks33
\MPscratchCnt=\count280
\MPscratchDim=\dimen175
\MPnumerator=\count281
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count282
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks34
)
(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epsto
pdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-
sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(89.62709pt, 418.25368pt, 89.6271pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(101.40665pt, 591.5302pt, 152.11pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=418.25368pt
* \textheight=591.5302pt
* \oddsidemargin=17.3571pt
* \evensidemargin=17.3571pt
* \topmargin=-7.86334pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=44.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 30.

(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 30.


(C:\Users\Lala\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
! Argument of \rmathbr@orig@goestoarg has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.32 $\goestoarg{
                 a}{b}$ %<- does not work
? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \rmathbr@orig@goestoarg was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.32 $\goestoarg{
                 a}{b}$ %<- does not work
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.32 $\goestoarg{
                 a}{b}$ %<- does not work
? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.32 $\goestoarg{
                 a}{b}$ %<- does not work
? 
! Too many }'s.
<recently read> }
                 
l.32 $\goestoarg{
                 a}{b}$ %<- does not work
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.34 
     
? 
[1

{C:/Users/Lala/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(Test12.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7565 strings out of 479283
 112372 string characters out of 2852377
 434818 words of memory out of 3000000
 24941 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 408839 words of font info for 46 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 68i,16n,75p,1197b,108s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{C:/Users/Lala/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvip
s/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}<C:/Users/Lala/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb><C:/Users/Lala/AppData/Local/Program
s/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb><C:/Users/Lala/AppData/
Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/Users/R
asmus/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pf
b><C:/Users/Lala/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/cm-supe
r/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on Test12.pdf (1 page, 36772 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

---

> I am running `pdflatex` 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MikTeX 21.3), and every package in my local distrubution was updated earlier today.

Comment: You can define `\def\goestoarg#1#2{\xrightarrow{#1\to#2}\allowbreak}`, you need not to use `\SetBreakableRel`.

Comment: @wipet Unless I am missing something, that doesn't work: the symbol ``\goestoarg`` does not get repeated on the new line. The aim is to have the symbol where line break takes place to be *duplicated*.

Comment: I cannot even get your MWE to build. There seems to be some weird conflict between `mathtools` and `rmathbr`.

Comment: @WillieWong May I ask if you are using the most recent version of ``rmathbr`` (from Dec 2020)? I tried to hint at this necessity in the beginning of the question; but I could've perhaps been more explicit :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only minimally tested, but this should work.
There may be a reason why this is not suggested in the documentation, but I haven't been able to reason out when something like this should fail to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{rmathbr}
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\newcommand{\goesto}{\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}} %works great
\SetBreakableRel{\goesto} %works great

\DeclareRobustCommand{\goestoarg}[2]{\brokenrel{\xrightarrow{#1\to#2}}}

\begin{document}


$e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e\goesto e$

$e\goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e \goestoarg{a}{b} e $ 
%$\Goestoarg{a}{b}$ %<- also does not work


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1)! If I may ask, what are you using for compilation? Overleaf / local distribution? I currently get errors when trying to build your solution (``! incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 46`` with the most recent packages/distribution (as quoted in the bottom of OP).

Comment: 1. Thank you, now your "main" solution (with two variable arguments) works nicely on initial testing.

2. I haven't gotten your "alternative" syntax (with one variable argument) to work. When you say "skip most of the code I included", which parts did you have in mind one should keep? (Of course, in addition to the three lines where one-variable ``\goestoarg`` is defined.) I double checked that I was using ``\goestoarg{a \to b}`` syntax here but simply says ``! undefined control sequence \goestoarg``. Any ideas?

Comment: Hang on... something is not right. Let me try to fix it first.

Comment: @LinearChristmas I took a few more minutes to trace through the code in the package... I think the above should work. All the various wrapper code that was included seems to be for some other purpose.

Comment: Thank you for doing this. Based on two initial tests, this works great, and has the benefit of looking simple syntactically! I will probably accept your answer in (at most) 24–48 h, maybe sooner, depending on some other tests. Until then, thank you again!

Comment: Currently, no complaints from me. Hopefully it stays this way :=). Thank you again for your time and assistance on this matter!