# unescaped macros

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is there a way to define a macro that does not start with `\`? for example, I'd like to have `->` expand to `\rightarrow` since I like reading raw LaTeX and 
`$\eps -> 0$` reads much nicer (to me...) than `$\eps\rightarrow0$` or even (the solution I have now) `$\eps\goto0$`.

I guess one could define `-` as an escape character and then use it to read the next character, if it is a `>` expand the whole shebang to `\rightarrow` and if not expand the `-` to a `-` and let the next character to its thing...I have no idea if what I just wrote makes any sense, nor how one would do it nor the possible pitfalls and reasons to avoid such behavior....

Ideas? Comments?

Comment: I'd say that `ε → 0` looks even nicer ;-)

Comment: @Stéphane: I notice the wink, but seriously, I'll say that I prefer ascii... :-o

Comment: This might be a duplicate: look up "mathcode".

Comment: yes...very similar to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/can-pdflatex-recognize-text-strings-and-replace-expand-them)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: This is why I love `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can decide to make `-` "active" only within math mode, and look ahead for a `>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathchardef\minuschar=\mathcode`-\relax
\mathcode`-="8000\relax
\begingroup\makeatletter\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~{\@ifnextchar{>}{\rightarrow\@gobble}{\minuschar}}}
\begin{document}
We can try $-\int$, $-\sum$, $x->0$, $x- >0$ etc.
\end{document}
```

When TeX encounters a character with catcode 11 or 12 (letter or other) in math mode, it looks up the character's mathcode. That's a number between `"0000` and `"8000` (hexadecimal). The value `"8000` is treated specially to mean "use the corresponding active character instead". I then defined `-` to look ahead for a `>`, and either put a `\rightarrow` and `\@gobble` the `>`, or put the minus character.

Comment: Small bug - `lccode` is reversed. Unforutunately comment markdown won't let me write it correctly, but it should be `lccode -= ~`.

Comment: I imagine @Bruno will fix it soon. In any case, in the following replace single quotes (`'`) with a grave quote (```). @Bruno's macro has the `lccode` definition reversed. It needs to be: `\lccode'~='-`. Remember, '=` in the preceding.

Comment: Don't use `\everymath` for setting the mathcode of `-` to `"8000`. Just define `\minuschar` before setting ``\mathcode`-="8000`` globally (the `\relax` is at least redundant anyway, a space will do better, as it is ignored, while `\relax` isn't). Also `\minuschar` can be more efficiently defined as ``\mathchardef\minuschar=\mathcode`-``.

Comment: Justin, egreg: you are both right. Edited to fix that.

Comment: The two `\relax` are still redundant. :) The end of line is all that's needed.

Comment: @egreg: true, but I'm used to `\catcode\endlinechar=9` in LaTeX3 catcodes, so it is safer that way. The only disadvantage of `\relax` here is that it slows TeX down just a tiny tiny bit.

Comment: Bruno and @egreg: I think this code won't typeset the expressions $-\int$ or $-\sum$ properly: the symbols that show up are (minus sign followed by) puny code table symbols rather than the result of the "normal" $\int$ and $\sum$ commands. :-(

Comment: @Mico: Surprising. I don't get that: see edit.

Comment: Indeed, with the latest version these issues have disappeared. :-) I may have run, perhaps, an earlier version of your code.

Comment: @Mico: good. Sorry that it took long to converge to good code.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest solution, as was observed in one of the comments is to directly type `→`. Both ConTeXt MkIV and LaTeX + `unicode-math` give the right output when using the correct unicode input.

If you are using LuaTeX, it is also possible to parse the input and convert `->` to `→`. Here is an example in ConTeXt that uses the `translate` module

```
\usemodule[translate]

\translateinput[->][→]
\translateinput[=>][⇒]

\enableinputtranslation

\starttext
$x - y = 0 => x = y$
\stoptext
```

Comment: I assume that it is possible to specify `→` as `\to` for those of us who like ascii characters?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Yes, using `\to` also works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Just for the record,

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{→}{\to}
```

allows for

```
$x→0$
```

with `pdflatex` (the file must be coded in UTF-8 and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` must be used, not `utf8x`). It also works with `xelatex` or `lualatex` (without [`unicode-math`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), of course, otherwise it would be nonsense).

Answer (score 7):

There's a package which provides exactly this service, called [semantic](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/semantic/).  It's designed for typsetting programming language semantics, so it provides five things: **math ligatures**; [inference rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) (with horizontal lines); [T-diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_diagram) (for representing compositions of compilers and interpreters); typesetting for reserved words; and **default shorthands**.  Obviously, we care about the two in bold.

Math ligatures let you do precisely the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[ligature]{semantic}

\mathlig{->}{\rightarrow}

\begin{document}
  \[ a_{>} -> b_{-} \]
\end{document}
```

This will typeset just the same as writing `\[ a_{>} \rightarrow b_{-} \]`.

You can define ligatures to be arbitrary sequences of characters (for precise details, [check the documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/semantic/semantic.pdf)), and if you specify the `[shorthand]` option to the package instead, it will define a default set (again, [the documentation has the list](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/semantic/semantic.pdf)).

As for limitations, there's only one that I've run into: having `b_-` alone doesn't work (whether or not it's at the end of math mode), because `-` is an initial character of a ligature (for instance, `a_>` works fine).  I have no clue why this is.  I would also guess that redefining `-` as an active character would break, but I've never tried.  Honestly, I've never run into it before, but now that someone mentioned similar things I thought I'd check.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly possible to assign a character other than `\` (backslash) to function as the start a control word (macro) in TeX. But, what would you gain? Even if all macros started with a `~` (tilde) character instead of a `\`, it wouldn't affect the length of the strings used to denote various commands, would it?

By the way, `\to` is a synonym for `\rightarrow`. Is `\to` short enough (and readable enough) for you? :-)

**Sort-of Lengthy Addendum** To make the specific character combination `->` into a "command" that typesets the equivalent of `\to` in math mode, you'd have to make the first character, `-`, "active" in TeX jargon and then define a macro that reads ahead to the next character; if that character is a `>`, you'd tell TeX to typeset `\rightarrow`, and if it's not, you'd instruct TeX to place the `-` character and the following character back into the input token stream.

Now, back to the question of how to make the "instruction" `->` execute the instruction `\rightarrow`. Study the code in the MWE below; the `\catcode` command makes the `-` active, and the following line provides the definition of the command. Note that we can't just place `-` back into the token stream, as TeX would find itself in an ever and deeper loop trying to resolve what to do with the command `-`. Instead, I use the command `\char` command to place a dash back into the token stream.

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\-=\active
\def-#1{\ifx>#1 \ensuremath{\rightarrow} \else \char`-#1 \fi}

\begin{document}
-> \quad -+ \quad -, \quad $-a$ \quad 5--9 \quad $x->0$
\end{document}
```

[image]
(Well, I'm sure I've left out some eventuality that'll make this code break down in some circumstances; I'll let our fellow TeX-SX hounds point out the mistakes...)

Comment: the main issue is not the length, but the readability. I can ofcourse define `\t` to be `\rightarrow`, but I want `->` to be `\rightarrow`...or rather I'm interested in finding out how it could be done....I certainly do not want to change anything else...I do not want _all_ macros to start with a tilde or any other character.

Comment: Please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Active characters are a mess. For example, the above will fail with `$x_{-}$`. Such things are more easy to handle using luatex where you can parse the input.

Comment: @Aditya, could you post an example in luatex? It would be very interesting! Your comment is one reason for using `\@ifnextchar` to test for the presence of `>`. Also, making `-` active only in math mode helps with the fact that otherwise `-` cannot be used in lengths etc.

Comment: Setting ``\catcode`~=0`` doesn't make `\to` and `~to` different. Moreover, activating `-` would break many things: with your definition, any space after `-` would be eaten up and, as Aditya observes, `x_{-}` will give an error.

Comment: @Bruno: See  my answer that uses the translate module for ConTeXt. The implementation is only a few lines that are part of `m-translate.mkiv`, but it builds upon some of the ConTeXt infrastructure.

Comment: @egreg and others: You guys are absolutely correct! I had a sinking feeling I had not thought through all circumstances... Anyway, for my own papers, I'll happily stick with typing $\to$!

Answer (score 1):

You can always make `-` an active character and assign a macro to it. Below I use a "delimited" macro to make `->` produce the "\rightarrow" token. The problem is `-` is redefined **everywhere**. You normally need to have some sort of scoping macro that turns active characters on and off:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\catcode `-=\active\def->{\ensuremath{\rightarrow}}
hello ->.
\end{document}
```

Search for "catcode" and "active characters" to learn more.

Comment: Right, so this does the first part...but leave a mess...since now `-` is active and I cannot use it anywhere except in a `->`....so, while this is a step in the right direction...its definitely the easier step... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned reading sources, I can suggest an alternative: set up your editor to display `\rightarrow` as `→`.

Emacs 24.5 with AucTeX does this if you enable `prettify-symbols-mode`:

[image: prettification]

(left: without `prettify-symbols-mode`; right: with `prettify-symbols-mode`. Same text in both buffers)