# Automatically convert `<=` to `\leq`

Tags: math-mode, automation

Is there a way to automatically convert instances of `<=` and `>=` to `\leq` and `\geq` ? I keep typing `<=` and `>=` by mistake.

Comment: If you're not using `=>` in any other contexts, a simple find and replace in your editor would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unescaped macros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30481/unescaped-macros)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's doable, in principle.

```
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\realless=\mathcode`<
\newcommand{\perhapsless}{\@ifnextchar={\leq\@gobble}{\realless}}
\mathcode`<="8000
{\catcode`<=\active \global\let<\perhapsless}

\mathchardef\realgreater=\mathcode`>
\newcommand{\perhapsgreater}{\@ifnextchar={\geq\@gobble}{\realgreater}}
\mathcode`>="8000
{\catcode`>=\active \global\let>\perhapsgreater}
\makeatother
```

Then `$a<=b<c$` will resolve into the correct symbols.

But I wouldn't rely on such automatisms. Better doing a "search and replace" and accustom to write `\leq` and `\geq` (or, as I do, `\le` and `\ge`).

Comment: Thanks =) Interesting solution (although not really pretty ;)

Comment: @Clément Just add it to the preamble and forget about it; however I don't recommend going this way.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it is better to instruct your text editor to correct automatically all your *favorite* misprints on fly. For my favorite editor WinEdt I have coded several such rules. Here are two rules which convert << and ББ (ББ is << typed on Russian keybord) into right quote '«' and automatically add the left quote '»' after current word.

```
STRING="<<"
  ENABLED=1
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[BeginGroup;Backspace;Backspace;SelWord(1);InsLabel('','«','»');EndGroup]"

STRING="ББ"
  ENABLED=1
  FILTER="TeX"
  ACTION="[BeginGroup;Repeat(2,'CMD(""Backspace"")');SelWord(1);InsLabel("""",""«"",""»"");EndGroup]"
```

In current version 6.0 of WinEdt these rulles are to placed into Active Strings throug **Options | Delimiters, Active Strings, Abbreviations...** menu.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you want unless you're using it anyway, but `siunitx` does this (and `<<`, `>>` to `$\ll$`, `$\gg$` respectively) automagically.