# pdfLaTeX: Convert € (euro symbol) to command

Tags: macros, pdftex, symbols

I would like to use € (\€ is also acceptable) in a way which `€{9x10,00}` (or `€[]`) produces `\SI{9x10,00}{€}` (so a particular case of converting € to command). Preferably, if typed alone (`€`) it should produce `\si{€}`, but that's probably extra detail.

The € symbol comes up a lot in some of my documents, and typing `\SI{#1}{€}` becomes annoying for someone (not me) that doesn't have much latex/programming experience and is used to word, hence the goal of such a simple final command.

I've tried:

```
\catcode`€=11 %also \catcode8364=11 which is 0x20AC, unicode for €

\newcommand{\€}[1]{\SI{#1}{€}}
```

but I get an error on catcode because € is utf-8. Also I'd be required to input `€{}` and `€` would become an error. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31133/106695) is close to what I want, but it relies on catcode.

Comment: why can't you use utf-8? the command you created `\newcommand{\€}[1]{\SI{#1}{€}}` works just fine here, under `XeLaTex`

Comment: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for good unicode support.

Comment: LaTeX is in the title for a reason :) And I can't use it because it's not provided by my distribution. Edit: Oh crap, no package, but binaries there. I just have never tried any of them, and always heard about compatibility issues. Only recently did I start to use latex in a more complex way

Comment: LaTeX is a language. pdfLaTeX is a compiler, so are XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. So maybe you should change your title to mention pdfLaTeX :) I don't think this is doable with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @ChristophFrings thank you for the clarification :) Title changed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's trivial with Unicode TeX engines like XeTeX or LuaTeX:

```
\catcode€=\active
\newcommand*€[1]{\SI{...}{...}}
```

The same applies to the other TeX engines with 8-bit input encodings (for example, `latin9`).

But it is trickier with UTF-8 bytes as input, because the Euro symbol consists of three UTF-8 bytes. Three bytes cannot be one active byte, also the category codes are usually not "letter" (11), but "other" (12). Thus these UTF-8 bytes cannot be used inside command names.

The following example uses LaTeX's `inputenc` machinery to assign the UTF-8 byte sequence to a macro:

- If the macro is immediately followed by the left curly brace (without spaces in between), then the macro takes the number as parameter and passes it to `\SI`.
- If the macro is immediately followed by the left square bracket, then an optional argument together with the number is passed to `\SI`.
- Otherwise the normal euro sign is printed without using a parameter.
- `\SI{9}{€}` works.
- € is robust for `\section` and the table of contents.
- For `hyperref`'s bookmarks, `\texteuro` can be used or an alternative for the bookmarks can be provided via `\texorpdfstring`. The euro symbol without arguments can be enabled by:

  ```
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\EuroMacro\texteuro}
  ```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\euro}{\texteuro}

\newcommand*{\sieuro}[2][]{\SI[{mode=text,#1}]{#2}{\euro}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\EuroMacro}{}
\protected\def\EuroMacro{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace\bgroup\sieuro{%
    \ltx@ifnextchar[\sieuro\texteuro
  }%
}
\newunicodechar{€}{\EuroMacro}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  €{12,34} and the currency is €.

  €[add-integer-zero]{.42}

  \sisetup{mode=text}
  \SI{9}{€}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A version with minimized number of packages in the TeX file. As variation, the euro symbol is generated by package `eurosym`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% UTF-8 input for non-Unicode TeX engines
\usepackage{eurosym}% euro sign
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Euro}{\euro}
\newcommand*{\sieuro}[2][]{\SI[{mode=text,#1}]{#2}{\Euro}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\EuroMacro}{%
  \ifx\@let@token\bgroup
    \expandafter\sieuro
  \else
    \ifx\@let@token[%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\sieuro
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\euro
    \fi
  \fi
}
\protected\def\EuroMacroAux{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\EuroMacro
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\EuroMacroAux}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  €{12,34} and the currency is €.

  €[add-integer-zero]{.42}

  \sisetup{mode=text}
  \SI{9}{€}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This has the same problem as egreg's answear (can't use `\SI{9}{€}`), requires an extra package, and was answeared (a bit) later.
But it would have solved my problem anyway, so +1. Maybe if you solve the problem before egreg? :)

Comment: @Olivetree I do not see your problem with "extra" packages. `\newunicodechar{€}{...}` is clearly easier to maintain than `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{...}`. The needed package `newunicodechar` is small, just provides the macro `\newunicodechar` and therefore does not have potential to conflict with other packages. Nevertheless I have added a variation in the updated answer, where the number of packages in the TeX file is reduced to quite a minimum.

Comment: I have no problem with packages. But I see using more packages (\usepackage{ltxcmds}) than another answear (which also had "short clean code") as a disadvantage. As long as all problems are solved, extra packages don't demean the answear. But you had the same problems, as big an answear, and more packages. Just that :)
Now you solved the problem, I can use `\SI{9}{€}`, so your solution is better!

Answer (score 8):

You can't set the category code of `€` in `pdflatex`, because it's three byte long. However, there are other methods.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym} % I can't stand textcomp euro symbol
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{€}{\olivetree@euro}
\newcommand{\olivetree@euro}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\EUR{\euro}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

You owe me €{100.23}; please, pay in €.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `siunitx` features for printing the number,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym} % I can't stand textcomp euro symbol
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{€}{\olivetree@euro}
\newcommand{\olivetree@euro}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\olivetree@euro@arg\euro}
\newcommand{\olivetree@euro@arg}[1]{\num{#1}\,\euro}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

You owe me €{100.23}; please, pay in €.

\end{document}
```

Some changes are needed for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\olivetree@euro}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\olivetree@euro@arg{€}}
\newcommand{\olivetree@euro@arg}[1]{\num{#1}\,€}
\newunicodechar{€}{\olivetree@euro}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

You owe me €{100.23}; please, pay in €.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but now I can't use `\SI{9}{€}`, it says \olivetree@euro@arg has an extra }. I can, however, use `{€}`. I know it sounds silly to want to want to use that, but this means it might be broken elsewhere. Do you have any idea? (this is still the exact solution I wanted).

Comment: @Olivetree You want too much. Besides, I can't recommend overloading the symbol.

Answer (score 5):

> `\€` is also acceptable

Then, a simple approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eurosym,siunitx}
\def\€#1{\SI{#1}{\mbox{\euro}}}
\begin{document}
\€{9x10,00}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Why does \def work when \newcommand doesn't? Does it parse every character until finding a `#` or `{`? (+1 for simplicity, and something new)

Comment: @Olivetree Yes, `\def` is not the same beast. Try  `\def\x2{xxxx}` and then \x2, \x22 and \x1  for example... The macro `\x2` work but the number is not the argument, , `\x22`  is not undefined because is `\x2` with a 2 pasted, and  `\x1`  is not undefined too, because the macro is really only  `\x` but fail anyway, because doesn't match its definition.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using pdftex (or tex) then `€` is *three* tokens not one. The first character has to be catcode 13 (active) to trigger the UTF-8 interpretation of the following two characters and so it is not possible to define `\€` as a TeX command name can only be a single character unless all the characters in the name are catcode 11 (letter).

If you use xetex or luatex then € is a single token and can be made active, or you can define `\€`.

That said it is possible to do what you want by defining the inputenc definition of € to be a command using siunitx.

Comment: Won't changing catcode of first character be dangerous? More characters use that.
Could you provide a more detailed example on how to make the whole character sequence usable in newcommand?

Comment: @Olivetree you can't change the catcode it has to be 13 and you can't use it in \newcommand. egreg shows how to use an inputenc declaration, as I suggest here.

Comment: I had misunderstood the beginning of your answear. It's much clearer now, thank you!