# How to setup auto-correction in LyX to automatically convert <= to \leq?

Tags: lyx, auto-completion

**Is there a way to configure LyX 2.3.4.4 to auto-correct `string1` into `string2`?
Specifically, I would like to type `<=` in an equation and get it replaced by `\leq` or simply by `≤`.**

- I know it can be achieved in some other text editors, such as TeXmacs
  and even MS Word, by defining an auto-correct pattern.
- I could define a shortcut, so that the combination of `SHIFT+< =`
  will activate the command `insert-math \leq`. It actually works, but
  it prevents typing `<` in equations.
- I noticed an option to enable auto-correction, under Tools ->
  Preferences -> Editing -> Input Completion. But when I check that box
  and apply the new settings, it doesn't seem to do anything at all.
  Even if it does, it is not obvious to me how I can setup
  auto-correction to my needs. I found an interesting file, though,
  called `autocorrect`, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\Resources`.
  The contents of this file seem to have a connection to what I'm
  trying to do.

Here it is:

```
#
# Idea of "autocorrection" and parts of this file are shamelessly stolen
# from TeXMacs (they give vdhoeven@texmacs.org as contact)
#
# We do it a bit differently and allow corrections only to combine a symbol
# and a char to a new symbol.
#
#

|                 ,    \lfloor
\lfloor           *    |,
|                 '    \lceil
\lceil            *    |'
,                 |    \rfloor
\rfloor           *    ,|
'                 |    \rceil
\rceil            *    '|
\llbracket        *    [[*
\rrbracket        *    ]]*

\cap              *    \sqcap
\cup              *    \sqcup
\vee              *    \curlyvee
\curlyvee         *    \curlyveeuparrow
\curlyveeuparrow  *    \curlyveedownarrow

<                 /    \nless
>                 /    \ngtr
<                 =    \leqslant
>                 =    \geqslant
\leqslant         /    \nleqslant
\geqslant         /    \ngeqslant
\leqslant         *    \leq
\geslant          *    \geq
\leq              /    \nleq
\geq              /    \ngeq
<                 <    \ll
\ll               <    \lll
>                 >    \gg
\gg               >    \ggg
\ll               =    \lleq
\lll              =    \llleq
\gg               =    \ggeq
\ggg              =    \gggeq
\ll               /    \nll
\lll              /    \nlll
\gg               /    \ngg
\ggg              /    \nggg
\lleq             /    \nlleq
\llleq            /    \nllleq
\ggeq             /    \nggeq
\gggeq            /    \ngggeq
<                 .    \lessdot
.                 >    \gtrdot
\leqslant         .    \lesseqdot
\gtrdot           =    \gtreqdot

<                 *    \prec
>                 *    \succ
\prec             /    \nprec
\succ             /    \nsucc
\prec             =    \preccurlyeq
\succ             =    \succcurlyeq
\preccurlyeq      /    \npreccurlyeq
\succcurlyeq      /    \nsucccurlyeq
\preccurlyeq      *    \preceq
\succcurlyeq      *    \succeq
\preceq           /    \npreceq
\succeq           /    \nsucceq
\npreceq          *    \precneqq
\nsucceq          *    \succneqq
\ll               *    \precprec
\precprec         *    \precprecprec
\gg               *    \succsucc
\succsucc         *    \succsuccsucc
\precprec         =    \precpreceq
\lll              *    \precprecprec
\precprecprec     =    \precprecpreceq
\succsucc         =    \succsucceq
\ggg              =    \succsuccsucc
\succsuccsucc     =    \succsuccsucceq
\precprec         /    \nprecprec
\precprecprec     /    \nprecprecprec
\succsucc         /    \nsuccsucc
\succsuccsucc     /    \nsuccsuccsucc
\precpreceq       /    \nprecpreceq
\precprecpreceq   /    \nprecprecpreceq
\succsucceq       /    \nsuccsucceq
\succsuccsucceq   /    \nsuccsuccsucceq

\prec             .    \precdot
\succ             .    \dotsucc
\precdot          .    \preceqdot
\dotsucc          .    \dotsucceq
\precprec         *    \llangle
\succsucc         *    \rrangle

<                 >    \lessgtr
>                 <    \gtrless
<                 ~    \lesssim
\lesssim          ~    \lessapprox
\prec             ~    \precsim
\precsim          ~    \precapprox
>                 ~    \gtrsim
\gtrsim           ~    \gtrapprox
\succ             ~    \gtrsim
\gtrsim           ~    \gtrapprox
\leq              *    \leqq
\geq              *    \geqq
\leq              >    \lesseqgtr
\geq              <    \gtrqless

-                 >    \rightarrow
<                 -    \leftarrow
\leftarrow        >    \leftrightarrow
\rightarrow       -    \longrightarrow
\leftarrow        -    \longleftarrow
\longleftarrow    >    \longleftrightarrow
=                 >    \Rightarrow


@                 *    \circ
\circ             /    \varnothing
\circ             +    \oplus
\circ             -    \ominus
@                 x    \otimes
\circ             :    \oover
\circ             .    \odot
@                 R    \circledR
@                 S    \circledS
\varnothing       *    \oslash
@                 \    \obslash
@                 @    \infty
\circ             <    \olessthan
\circ             >    \ogreaterthan
\circ             &    \owedge
\circ             |    \obar
\obar             *    \ovee
\circ             v    \ovee
\circ             @    \infty
@@                *    \varocircle
-@                @    \infty
\circ             *    \box
\box              +    \boxplus
\box              -    \boxminus
\box              x    \boxtimes
\box              .    \boxdot
\box              /    \boxslash
\box              \    \boxbslash
\box              @    \boxcircle
\boxcircle        *    \boxbox
\box              |    \boxbar
\box              *    \bullet
\bullet           *    \blacksquare

=                 *    \asymp
\asymp            *    \equiv
\equiv            *    \asympasymp
\asympasymp       *    \simsim
~                 *    \sim
\sim              ~    \approx
\approx           -    \approxeq
\sim              -    \simeq
\sim              =    \cong
=                 /    \neq
\asymp            /    \nasymp
\equiv            /    \nequiv
\asympasymp       /    \nasympasymp
\simsim           /    \nsimsim
\sim              /    \nsim
\approx           /    \napprox
\simeq            /    \nsimeq
\cong             /    \ncong

#|   \|
|                 *    \shortmid
\shortmid         *    \varshortmid
|                 |    \||
\||               |    \interleave
\||               *    \shortparallel
|                 -    \vdash
\vdash            -    \longvdash
\||               -    \Vdash
\Vdash            -    \longVdash
\interleave       -    \Vvdash
\Vvdash           -    \longVvdash
-                 |    \dashv

<                 |    \vartriangleleft
\vartriangleleft  *    \blacktriangleleft
\vartriangleleft  /    \ntriangleleft
\vartriangleleft  =    \trianglelefteqslant
\trianglelefteqslant / \ntrianglelefteqslant
\trianglelefteqslant * \trianglelefteq
\trianglelefteq   /    \ntriangleqleft
|                 >    \vartriangleright
\vartriangleright *    \blacktriangleright
\vartriangleright /    \ntriangleright
\vartriangleright =    \trianglerighteq
\trianglerighteq  /    \ntriangleqright
\trianglerighteq  *    \trianglerighteqslant
\trianglerighteqslant  /    \ntrianglerighteqslant

-                 *    \um
+                 -    \pm
\pm               *    \upm
-                 +    \mp
\mp               *    \ump
@                 =    \circeq
=                 @    \eqcirc
-                 @    \multimap
.                 =    \doteq
.                 .    \ldots
\ldots            *    \cdots
\cdots            *    \hdots
\hdots            *    \vdots
\ddots            *    \ddots
\iddots           *    \iddots
\udots            *    \udots
:                 =    \assign
+                 =    \plusassign
-                 =    \minusassign
/                 *    \div
*                 *    \ast
\ast              *    \times
\times            *    \cdot

<                 *    \subset
\subset           *    \in
\in               *    \sqsubset
\subset           =    \subseteq
\subseteq         /    \nsubseteq
\subseteq         *    \subseteqq
\sqsubset         *    \langle
\langle           *    \leftslice
\leftslice        *    \subset

\subseteq         /    \nsubseteq
\subseteqq        /    \nsubseteqq
\nsubseteqq       *    \subsetneq
\subsetneq        *    \varsubsetneq
\varsubsetneq     *    \subsetneqq
\subsetneqq       *    \varsubsetneqq
\subset           +    \subsetplus
\subsetplus       =    \subsetpluseq
\subseteq         +    \subsetpluseq
\in               /    \nin
>                 *    \supset
\supset           /    \nsupset
\supset           =    \supseteq
\supseteq         /    \nsupseteq
\supseteq         *    \supseteqq
\supseteq         /    \nsupseteq


\supseteqq        /    \nsupseteqq
\supseteq         /    \supsetneq
\supset           +    \supsetplus
\supsetplus       =    \supsetpluseq
\supseteq         +    \supsetpluseq
\supset           *    \ni
\ni               /    \nni

#
# The following is available in TeXMacs, but not (yet) in LyX
#

#--|    \longdashv
#|           =    \vDash
#\vDash      =    \longvDash
#||=    \VDash
#||==    \longVDash
#|           /    \nmid
#||/    \nparallel
#|*/    \nshortmid
#||*/    \nshortparallel
#|-/    \nvdash
#||-/    \nVdash
#-|/    \ndashv
#-||/    \ndashV
#|=/    \nvDash
#||=/    \nVDash
#=|/    \nDashv
#=||/    \nDashV
#
#<=**>    \lesseqqgtr
#>=**<    \gtreqqless
#<>/   \nlessgtr
#></   \ngtrless
#<~/   \nlesssim
#<~/*    \lnsim
#<~~/    \nlessapprox
#<~~/*    \lnapprox
#<*~/    \nprecsim
#<*~/*    \precnsim
#<*~~/    \nprecapprox
#<*~~/*    \precnapprox
#>~/   \ngtrsim
#>~/*    \gnsim
#>~~/    \ngtrapprox
#>~~/*    \gnapprox
#>*~/   \nsuccsim
#>*~/*    \succnsim
#>*~~/    \nsuccapprox
#>*~~/*    \succnapprox
#<=**/    \nleqq
#>=**/    \ngeqq
#<=*>/    \nlesseqgtr
#>=*</    \ngtreqless
#<=**>/    \nlesseqqgtr
#>=**</    \ngtreqqless
#<=*/*    \lneq
#<=**/*    \lneqq
#<=**/**    \lvertneqq
#>=*/*    \gneq
#>=**/*    \gneqq
#>=**/**    \gvertneqq
#[[                *    \llbracket
#]]                *    \rrbracket
#EE                a    \amalg
#EE                d    \partial
#EE                p    \wp
#EE                n    \cap
#EE                u    \cup
#EE                w    \wedge
#\wedge            *    \curlywedge
#\curlywedge       *    \curlywedgeuparrow
#\curlywedgeuparrow   * \curlywedgedownarrow
#\curlywedgedownarrow * \wedges
#EE                v    \vee
#EE                x    \times

# <***/    \nsqsubset
# <***=    \sqsubseteq
# <***=/    \nsqsubseteq
# >*=/**    \varsupsetneq
# >*=*/*    \supsetneqq
# >*=*/**    \varsupsetneqq
# >***    \sqsupset
# >***/    \nsqsupset
# >***=    \sqsupseteq
# >***=/    \nsqsupseteq

# >****    \rangle
# \rangle  *     \rightslice

# EE                l    \bigl
# EE                m    \bigm
# EE                r    \bigr
# EE                @    \bigop
# EE                L    \int
```

- Lastly, I found this thread,
  [Automatically convert `<=` to `\leq`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31133/214192), which suggests
  another approach, where the corresponding strings are being replaced
  during compilation. However, this is completely different than what
  I'm trying to do, since it is inefficient, and prone to errors. I
  want to replace `<=` by `\leq` during typing.

So I hope I made my question clear enough, and if you can help me find a solution I will appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found two solutions. One is a workaround, and the other uses LyX auto-correct functionality.

1. It is possible to download and install auto-text substitution tools, such as [Phrase Express](https://www.phraseexpress.com/) and the open-source [Beeftext](https://beeftext.org/).
2. The file I posted above is indeed related. You can go to `Tools -> Preferences -> Editing -> Input Completion` and check the box `Autocorrection`. Press OK. After that, create a new equation, and enter `<=`. You'll notice, at the left bottom, there's a message `Autocorrect Off ('!' to enter)`. So follow the instruction and press `SHIFT+!`. Now auto-correct is activated, and phrases like `<=` will be replaced with `\leq`.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution! Consider marking your own answer as Accepted so the question is marked as answered.